# Image not getting displayed in exported excel from VF page

Tags: visualforce, excel

I am exporting a VF page as Excel document. But i cant seem to get the logo put to display in the exported excel sheet.
All i get for the image is red X

I did see some post to upload the image as document and use the document url to display the image.

[How to display image from Static Resource in Excel sheet (generated from VF Page)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32065/how-to-display-image-from-static-resource-in-excel-sheet-generated-from-vf-page)

[Referencing Externally Available Images Absolute URL with My Domain?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37162/referencing-externally-available-images-absolute-url-with-my-domain)

In one of the post, they have asked to use the following url
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015a00000030EqL&oid=00D30000000X7qS&lastMod=1392744621000

What does the id and oid represent ?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing the image? Static Resource or Document object?

Comment: Document object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oid` is the org ID (Setup  -> Company Profile -> Company Information -> Salesforce.com Organization ID) and the `id` is a Document ID. If the Document has "Externally Available Image" set the URL will allow access without authentication which is what you probably want from your spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah that makes sense