# images not displaying in word document

Tags: visualforce, document

I am generating word document. In the document images are not displaying in header. Images are getting from documents. Below is my code..

My VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="GenerateWordController" contentType="application/vnd.msWord#HR_WordDocument.doc" cache="true" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" readOnly="true">
<apex:image value="{!ESLogo}" width="30" height="30"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:image value="{!ESLogo1}"/>
```

My Controller:

```
public class GenerateWordController
{
    public String ESLogo                       { get; set; }
    public String ESLogo1                      { get; set; }

    public GenerateWordController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {   
        tempString = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';

        ESLogo = tempString;
        ESLogo1 = tempString;

        List<document> documentList = [SELECT id, 
                                               NAME 
                                        FROM   document 
                                        WHERE  NAME LIKE 'ESLogo%' 
                                        ORDER  BY NAME ];
        if(documentList.size() > 0)
        {
          ESLogo = ESLogo + documentList[0].id;
          ESLogo1 = ESLogo1 + documentList[1].id;
          System.debug('documentList[0].id+++++++++' + documentList[0].id);
          System.debug('documentList[1].id+++++++++' + documentList[1].id);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the image id's in system.debug, but images are not displaying in word document.

Comment: I am pretty sure that image is stored as link, not as picture itself. Can you try to use insead of apex:image just img tag with src as binary data -- like here http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/

Comment: Hi Kurunve, I tried with <img> tag but not get.

Comment: then, there is no way to do it in SF. You can try s-docs extension, it has 2 free templates, and that may be what you need, or al least suits your request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar issue while exporting it to excel.
[Image not getting displayed in exported excel from VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110979/image-not-getting-displayed-in-exported-excel-from-vf-page)

Build your url like this https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015a00000030EqL&oid=00D30000000X7qS&lastMod=1392744621000

where id = documentid and oid is organization id
and make sure you have the image as externally available in your document. Hope this helps

Comment: yes, it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
servlet/servlet.imageserver?id=record id&oid=orgid
```

instead of

```
servlet/servlet.filedownload?file=recordid
```

`The servlet/servlet.imageserver?id=` allows us only to view the image in browser window while the `servlet/servlet.filedownload?file=,`downloads the file from your browser to download location .

Comment: Hi Kalpesh, this is also correct. thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This Can simply be achieved in 2 ways

1.Copying the link like shown in below article

Right click the image itself and copy its full URL. In Google Chrome, you would right click the image and click Copy image address. In Firefox, you would right click the image and click Copy image location. In Internet Explorer, you would right click the image and click Properties, and then copy the URL from the "Address (URL)" field in the following pop-up window.
[image]
You can now add this image into your template by clicking the Add Image button icon in the

2.The second way it putting the DOC id and ORG id in below format

```
<img id="theImage" src="https://swapnilsrivastav-dev-ed--c.na46.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150H00000GEhAm&oid=00Di0000000joS6&lastMod=1576580776000" />
```

Thanks